# Hide the Android Notification bar on a Sencha Touch 2 app

Tags: android, extjs, hide, android-notification-bar, notification-bar

I've successfully got my application compiled into an apk file, and deployed to my Android devices.

But when I run it there, the notification bar is present and I'd like it to be fullscreen, without the notification bar.

This is the bar at the top of the screen, with the battery usage, wifi/3G connection, new email icon, etc.

How do we hide this in our compiled apps with Sencha Touch 2?

I have set fullscreen: true in the config of the first view which is loaded (the log in screen), and have also set:

```
Ext.application({
   viewport: {
      autoMaximize: true
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could change this in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application>
  <activity
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
  </activity>
  ...
</application>
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, when compiling the apk with Sencha's compiler, we don't get a chance to edit the AndroidManifest.xml.

Is there a way to edit the AndroidManifest.xml after the apk has been created?

Comment: Sorry I am not fimiliar with Sencha. But you could open the APK with a Zip archiver, such 7-Zip and edit/replace the AndroidManifest.xml. But watch for any signing problems after editing the APK.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually modify the AndroidManifest.xml template in the SenchaCmd to get this, as explained in the [Sencha forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?192523-How-to-create-generate-apk-for-Sencha-Touch-2.0/page2).

That file will be in `Sencha/Cmd/<CmdVersion>/stbuild/st-res/android/AndroidManifest.xml`. You need to set the theme property on the `application` tag like this: `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"`

with the whole tag looking like:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="%s" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

However, this solution is still extremely crappy and I'd love to see something that works without patching Sencha's code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this to make the screen fullscreen `this.setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);` before `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

OR

add `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` and 
`this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)` before `setContentView`

For example:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
/**sets Theme and Style (must be set BEFORE super.onCreate)*/
this.setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

OR

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
/**Changes Window. Removes title and/or notification bar (must be set BEFORE setContentView)*/
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

(Or you can do it via the Manifest as what homer_simpson said.)

Comment: This is native Android, or Java code. With Sencha Touch 2 we're writing JavaScript which is then compiled into an APK. I don't think I can use this sorry.

Unless you know how I can add Java code to my Sencha Touch 2 app before I compile it to an APK?